# cannot connect to redis container from app container

Tags: docker, redis

I follow the django channels tutorial to build a simple chat app.
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html
, 
**it can work on my local machine with redis without docker.**

then now i want to put it into docker containers by docker compose file, but seems app cannot connect to redis container, i already try and google for two days, but seems all methods cannot work.

so want to ask for help here

**folder structure**

```
my_project
  - mysite(django app)
     - ... somefolder and files
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockfile
  - requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      # current directory
      context: .
    ports:
      #host to image
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      # map directory to image, which means if something changed in
      # current directory, it will automatically reflect on image,
      # don't need to restart docker to get the changes into effect
      - ./mysite:/mysiteRoot/mysite
    command: >
      sh -c "
             python3 manage.py makemigrations &&
             python3 manage.py migrate &&
             python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5-alpine
    ports:
      #host to image
      - "6379:6379"
```

**Dockfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER Aaron Wei.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

EXPOSE 8000

# Setup directory structure
RUN mkdir /mysiteRoot
WORKDIR /mysiteRoot/mysite/

# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /mysiteRoot/requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN apk add build-base python-dev py-pip jpeg-dev zlib-dev
ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib
RUN pip install -r /mysiteRoot/requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

# Copy application
COPY ./mysite/ /mysiteRoot/mysite/

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

**Django settings file**

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's0d^&2@s^126#6dsm7u4-t9pg03)if$dq##xxouht)#%#=o)r0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'chat',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('0.0.0.0', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7966fe4962f7        tourmama_copy_app    "sh -c '\n       pyth…"   21 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   tourmama_copy_app_1
61446d04c4b2        redis:5.0.5-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"    27 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   tourmama_copy_redis_1
```

Then the error in console shows :

```
app_1    | HTTP GET /chat/dadas/ 200 [0.01, 172.19.0.1:39468]
app_1    | WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/dadas/ [172.19.0.1:39470]
app_1    | Exception inside application: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('0.0.0.0', 6379)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 179, in __call__
app_1    |     return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
app_1    |     await inner_instance(receive, send)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
app_1    |     [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 59, in await_many_dispatch
app_1    |     await task
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 425, in receive
app_1    |     real_channel
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 477, in receive_single
app_1    |     index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 324, in _brpop_with_clean
app_1    |     async with self.connection(index) as connection:
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 813, in __aenter__
app_1    |     self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 70, in pop
app_1    |     conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py", line 178, in create_redis
app_1    |     loop=loop)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 108, in create_connection
app_1    |     timeout, loop=loop)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 388, in wait_for
app_1    |     return await fut
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py", line 19, in open_connection
app_1    |     lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 959, in create_connection
app_1    |     raise exceptions[0]
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 946, in create_connection
app_1    |     await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 464, in sock_connect
app_1    |     return await fut
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 494, in _sock_connect_cb
app_1    |     raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
app_1    |   [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('0.0.0.0', 6379)
app_1    | WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/dadas/ [172.19.0.1:39470]
```

is anyone has any idea how to connect to redis container from app?
thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change :

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('0.0.0.0', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

to

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('redis', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

in your `Django settings file`.

When you set up containers from compose they are all connected to the default network created by compose. `redis` is in this case the DNS name of `redis` container and will be resolved to container ip automatically

Comment: oh yeah thank u very much , it works now !! i originally i thought was my docker compose file wrong. turn out to be settings file wrong

Comment: I've looking for a solution for some time now. This fixed my issue. Thanks alot.